# url for ajax is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

my ajax code is

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://www.web-tutor99.com/ajax/template0.php",
  beforeSend: function() {
    $('div#divLoading').show();
  },
  complete: function() {
    $('div#divLoading').hide();
  },
  success: function(data) {
    var menuStyleSheets = $("head .menuStyleSheets");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < menuStyleSheets.length; i++) {
      //code
      $(menuStyleSheets[i]).remove();
    }
    $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" class="menuStyleSheets" href="styleSheets/styleSheet' + index + '.css" >').appendTo("head");
    $("#menuThm").remove();
    $(".showMenu").append(data);
    temp = Tempo.prepare('list');
    createMenu();
  },
  error: function() {
    alert("try another theme");
  },
  type: "GET",
})
```

and in the tamplate.php file i'm just echoing the html code but the ajax call is not fetching it showing the error alert, please help me, Thank you.

Comment: If you don't post the error in your console and the template.php is impossible to reply

Answer (score 1):

**Ensure your Syntax is Correct / No Cross Origin Issues**

Try removing the trailing `,` at the end of your AJAX call (after your `type` parameter). It's likely that your code is expecting another parameter that isn't there :

```
type: "GET",
```

Additionally, you will want to ensure that you are making this request from the same domain, otherwise you may encounter a cross-site  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" scripting error.

**Use Your Developer Tools To Examine The Request**

You may want to try using the Developer Tools (F12) within your browser and try examining the Request / Response content within the Network tab (seen below using Chrome) :

[image]

This should give you any specific server-side errors within the response if they are present.